# iOS: is it possible to read /private directory in iOS

Tags: ios, file-permissions, nsfilemanager

Is it possible to read the /private directory on an iOS device? I know it is owned by root. But do the developers even have read permissions on that directory?

```
NSArray *contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/private" error:nil];
```

return nil. 
whereas

```
NSArray *contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/" error:nil];
```

returns contents.

Thanks.

Comment: This can't be done on a non-jailbroken device running a regular app store app.

Answer (score 0):

On Unix, if you want to get all file's name of an directory, you must have execute permission on every note of the directory.(eg: /Users/myname, you must have permission on / and /Users and /Users/myname)

So as you must have execute permission on your app, so you must have execute permission on the root directory.

That why you `NSArray *contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/" error:nil];` return contents.